# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS qt plugin

Tags: ros, plugin, ide, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I'm having trouble trying to use Qt for my ROS projects.

First I tried with standard Qt from official webpage, running it from terminal and with some path configurations I managed to make autocomplete work (only in c++ files) but not in include files and also no building was possible because I got some errors as "undefined reference to std::__cxx" from g++ compiler.

Then, I removed Qt and installed ros qt pluguin following this tutorial: [link](https://ros-industrial.github.io/ros_qtc_plugin/_source/How-to-Install-Users.html)

Now I have qtcreator-ros but I can only launch it from desktop app. When I try to run it from terminal, I get a core dump:

[image: image description]

edit: I realized that using sudo solves the issue.

Anyway, I run it from applications, I can create a workspace where I select my catkin_ws.

I try to build I get this catkin_make error:

16:37:49: Running steps for project catkin_ws...
16:37:49: Could not start process "catkin_make" --cmake-args -G 'CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles'
Error while building/deploying project catkin_ws (kit: Imported Kit)
When executing step "CatkinMake Step"
16:37:50: Elapsed time: 00:01.

So I check my kits and there is something weird...

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

My kits are not well configured, and I don't know what should I do. It's supposed to be configured automatically, and I don't know where the error is.

Any idea?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280600/ros-qt-plugin/) by [RogerPi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28685/rogerpi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2018-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally I managed to **solve it!**!

The first problem is solved running it using sudo, I suppose is because the program is in opt and some permissions might be unset.

To solve Kits problems I reinstalled qt several times, until I realized that the configuration was always the same, so I deleted ~/.config/QtProject folder. I assume that having different Qt, installing, un-installing, maybe I touched something I shouldn't.

When I deleted configuration and run it again, there was only 1 kit and everything is set up properly. But building made the same error:

16:37:49: Running steps for project catkin_ws... 16:37:49: Could not start process "catkin_make" --cmake-args -G 'CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles' Error while building/deploying project catkin_ws (kit: Imported Kit) When executing step "CatkinMake Step" 16:37:50: Elapsed time: 00:01.

To solve this, just go to your workspace and run manually "catkin_make --cmake-args -G 'CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles' "

After doing it for first time, you will be able to do it using Qt.

I just figured out these things trying and trying, but I don't have a clear idea of what's going on. So if anybody has any comment on this, it will be welcome!

---

Originally posted by [RogerPi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28685/rogerpi/) with karma: 36 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-23**:\

> The first problem is solved running it using sudo, [..]

I'm happy for you that you got things to work, but *never* run programs as `root` (which is what `sudo` sort of does) unless it's absolutely, really, necessary. It'll just complicate things later on, and should not be necessary at all ..

**Comment by [RogerPi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28685/rogerpi/) on 2018-01-23**:
No, I'm not running it as root, it was just for testing, but I know I can screw something in my computer easily. But I still don't understand why I can't run it from terminal, but I can by desktop application...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-23**:
.. to run something as simple as Qt Creator.

The fact that it doesn't work without `sudo` points to issues with how your OS is setup, which would be something to check.

Google-searching for "qt platform plugin xcb" returns a host of results.

**Comment by [Levi-Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/27969/levi-armstrong/) on 2018-01-24**:
After you ran "catkin_make --cmake-args -G 'CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles' " were you able to build from within Qt Creator?

**Comment by [RogerPi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28685/rogerpi/) on 2018-01-25**:
Yes, after doing it for first time in terminal I can build from terminal or Qt with no problem.